# New route not showing in React Native Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am extremely new in React Native, tried to adding a testing screen in drawer, but I couldn't.

```
import { createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation"
/* Some imports here neglected...*/

/*
* icon size
* */
const iconSize = 18

const IntegratedNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  bottomNavigator: { screen: BottomNavigator, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  something: { screen: Something, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  something2: { screen: SomethingElse, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
})

export const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Tabs: {
      screen: IntegratedNavigation,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: "Explore",
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon icon={"search"} size={iconSize} color={tintColor}/>
        ),
        header: null,
      },
    },
    PartnersScreen: {
      screen: PartnersScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: "Partners",
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon icon={"safety"} size={iconSize} color={tintColor}/>
        ),
      },
    },
    HelloScreen: {
      screen: PartnersScreen, /*This is a testing new drawer tab that never appear!*/
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: "Test!",
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
          <Icon icon={"test"} size={iconSize} color={tintColor}/>
        ),
      },
    },
  }, {
    contentOptions: {
      inactiveTintColor: color.palette.lightBlack,
      activeTintColor: color.primary,
    },
    contentComponent: props => (<MenuUserInfo drawerItemsProps={props}/>),
    drawerWidth: 240,
  },
)
```

As a test, I just wanted to duplicate "PartnersScreen" as another tab. But the new route never appear. I couldn't figure out which other file I need to modify. Any idea?

Comment: do you have an icon={"test"}? (just trying to rule out some causes), maybe if it couldnt render the icon it will fail and not render the entry on the drawer